# Get Ghosting Autodesk forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

is it possible to get the current state of the ghosting settings in the forge viewer?

I basically want to be able to do something like

if(ghosting === true) {do something} else {do something else }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about this option in the settings panel ?

[image: Ghost hidden objects]

If so, you can get the state of this setting (and all others) like that :

`viewer.getState().renderOptions.appearance.ghostHidden`

Comment: Alternatively, you can check the current state of the viewer settings via `viewer.prefs.get(Autodesk.Viewing.Private.Prefs3D.GHOSTING)`.